# How to use get_post_custom_values to return the value of an array

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a custom post type called `albums` and a custom field therein called `tracklist` which is an array containing `song_title` and `duration`. I would like to print a list of the songs on each album.

It's helpful for me to think of the array hierarchy like so:

```
albumlist
  album
    tracklist
      track
        song_title
        duration
```

So far I figured out how to drill down to the tracklist array, but not how to display the values of the song titles within it.

```
$albums = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'album',
  'meta_key'  => 'tracklist'
));

if($albums) {
  foreach($albums as $album) {
    echo get_the_title($album->ID) . "<br>"; // Displays album's title
    $tracklist = get_post_custom_values('tracklist', $album->ID);

    foreach($tracklist as $track) {
      echo $track . "<br>"; // Displays "12" (there are 12 tracks on this album)
    }
  }
}
```

Anyway, I've been working at this for a couple hours trying to solve it myself, but it's getting late! Once I get to the `tracklist` array, how do I drill inside the track and get the song title?

Thanks for any help you can proffer.

Comment: `get_post_custom_values` gets all the custom fields for a post, if you want individual custom field, use `get_post_meta` instead. See my answer below.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde: I think get_post_custom_values return all the values of a custom field. Not like that it returns all the custom fields of a post. Refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values

Comment: Yes but the user is only wanting one particular field(tracklist), that field being an array doesn't change anything, `get_post_meta` would be the better choice here. If the asker could `print_r()` the meta data he gets, it would be alot easier for everyone to advise him or her on how to loop over that data(we need to see the structure of that data).

Comment: @booota Ohh my bad... I got it confused with get_post_custom!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde: my pleasure to remind you... hehe :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
foreach($tracklist as $track) {
  echo $track . "<br>"; // Displays "12" (there are 12 tracks on this album)
}
```

to

```
foreach($tracklist as $key => $value ) {
    echo "$key  => $value ('tracklist')<br />"; // Displays "12" (there are 12 tracks on this album)
}
```

then what you get?

Comment: This is correct, you can simply echo `$value ` though, if you don't want the array info (useful for debugging).

Comment: @Wyck: yeah right.

Comment: OK, that seemed to work. Also, a great thing I learned was using var_dump($tracklist); really useful to be able to see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$albums = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'album',
        'meta_key'  => 'tracklist'
));

if(isset($albums) && !empty($albums))
{
    foreach($albums as $album)
    {
        echo get_the_title($album->ID) . "<br>"; // Displays album's title
        $tracklist = get_post_meta($album->ID, 'tracklist', true);

        if(isset($tracklist) && !empty($tracklist))
        {
            foreach($tracklist as $track)
            {
                 echo $track . "<br>"; // Displays "12" (there are 12 tracks on this album)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No Tracklist Added";
        }
    }
}
```